# Typing doesn't work, shortcut keys work

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard, search, google-search

I get into this problem often, almost once a week. All on a sudden my keyboard isn't typing anything. Not on any software. I try to open notepad, press every letter, nothing gets typed on notepad, neither on google chrome, neither on start menu. This problem always starts when I am using chrome.

Now the weird things are, which I can't make any sense of:

1. If I click on text input field(not textarea) on any website, the keyboard starts working again.!
2. Every shortcut key works! Like, ctrl + a or alt + tab. It's not like a key is stuck because I tried pressing only the winkey or only arrow keys, everything works! It just won't type!
3. Sometime it gets fixed automatically after 5/10 minutes. Even if I don't do anything.

I have 2 keyboards connected. One mechanical(razer blackwidow chroma tournament, this doesn't have numpad) and the other one is a normal keyboard with numpad(Asus cerberus). I hardly use the other keyboard, it's just connected. When the "Not Typing" problem happens, both keyboards shows the same problem.

Sometime it gets so annoying, I am in an important meeting, presenting something and this happens. Any idea how to find out what the actual problem is and how to fix this?

Comment: "razer blackwidow chroma tournament" .. yeah, I have one of these too.  The drivers (and the chroma crap) REALLY SUCK.  I would suggest uninstalling ALL OF IT and living without it long enough to know if the problem goes away.  Your keyboard will work find in the meantime but you will need to cancel the driver install at every boot (one time) or workaround it using one of the methods described here on SU.  In the least, you will enjoy having HUNDREDS of MB of RAM back and CPU power not being wasted by poorly written .net code.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I don't have the razer software installed, never had. I've reinstalled the drivers after your comment, yes the problem is still here. I've had the exact same setup for almost 2 years, never had any problem with this. Recently I've reinstalled windows and changed my headset to G733, and about 2/3 weeks ago I got this huge windows update....and then this all started. I am not sure which is exactly causing the issue. I am thinking maybe some chrome update? Seems to happen only while using chrome. I spend most of my time on IDEs

Comment: I am very happy to hear that you aren't running any of their crap. :)  "Reinstalled the drivers".. what drivers?  Keyboards don't need drivers that don't already come with windows.. that was the point I was making.. and I too spend most of my time with IDEs. :)  Good luck brother.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I was talking about these. https://imgur.com/a/XHwr1t5

Thank you. Since I've started using firefox yesterday, this didn't occur. I am trying to switch to a different browser other than chrome. Let's see